# Exploring Testnet's Blockchain

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, testnet, block-explorer

I have synced my testnet node. I can send and receive transactions, but I would like to see how they look like for someone viewing the blockchain (specially the ringCT ones). So far, though, I couldn't find a single working block explorer that supported the testnet, and to my surprise, apparently there is no way to look into the blockchain in my local machine only using wallet commands! Am I missing something? Please let me know if what is the best way to access that information.

Comment: Daemon commands work though, eg: print_tx inserttxidhere

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check this block explorer (according to [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/51u6ab/check_ringct_in_action_testnet_monero_network_has/)) :

http://xmrtestbbzl275vy.onion/

tor2web proxy: http://xmrtestbbzl275vy.onion.link/

Comment: Thanks, that actually worked! For some reason I tried those links earlier today but they weren't loading.